# AIR FullScreen not applied on iOS

Tags: ios, flash, ipad, air, adobe

We are currently trying to bring our Flash/AIR application to an iPad for testing.
Basically, it works, but the app is displayed in a very small window.

The original swf is set to 2048x1536 (which should be the correct iPad resolution). However, it seems as if the iPad is trying to fit 2048x1536 into that small window at the center of the display.

If I press on "2x" to make the app bigger, it scales everything up, and by that making everything very pixelated. It looks really awkward.

On desktop and Android, everything is working fine, of course.

Here is the application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
<id>com.xxx.xxx</id>
<versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
<filename>xxx</filename>
<name>xxx</name>

<initialWindow>
  <title>xxx</title>
  <content>xxx.swf</content>
  <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
  <transparent>false</transparent>
  <visible>true</visible>
  <minimizable>true</minimizable>
  <maximizable>true</maximizable>
  <resizable>true</resizable>
  <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
  <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
  <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
  <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
  <width>2048</width>
  <height>1536</height>
</initialWindow>

<supportedProfiles>desktop mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>

<iPhone>
  <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
  <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
  <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
  <string>wifi</string>
  <string>microphone</string>
    </array>
  <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
  <string>YES</string>]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
</application>
```

Here is how I package the *.ipa file:

```
adt -package  -target ipa-test   -provisioning-profile  bat\certificates\xxx.mobileprovision  -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "bat\certificates\xxx.p12" -storepass xxx air\xxx.ipa application.xml -C output .
```

I am developing from Windows 7, using [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/). I also tried different combinations of renderMode, fullScreen, width/height, but nothing helped. The app is simply much too small on the iPad, and definitely **NOT** fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a 2X-button on the iPad, you are running an iPhone app, not a "real" iPad app. The problem is in the XML. You need to specify the UIDeviceFamily to get it to compile as an iPad app: leebrimelow.com/?p=2764

Comment: There is no iPad tag for application.xml files ;)

Comment: @TheSHEEEP: I see. Still, you probably need to specify the UIDeviceFamily, or have some other setting to tell the compiler to make an iPad app: http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=2764

Comment: Yep, I was missing the UIDeviceFamily. Thanks! Could you edit your answer so that I can mark it as the solution? :)

Comment: Using the non-retina resolution does look rather crappy to be honest, upscaled apps actually look worse on the iPad3. I'd rather recommend getting it right in the first place. Check this out: http://www.overdigital.com/2012/05/08/the-new-retina-ipad-and-adobe-air/

Answer (score 1):

see this thread.
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?p=43643
application.xml

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
<!-- iPhone support -->
<!--<string>1</string> -->
<!-- iPad support -->
<string>2</string>  <==== for iPad
</array>
```

I got success to comple.